# How do i show that one sequence is equal to another?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have a sequence $$a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\quad \quad  a_1 = 1$$
i have to show that$$a_n=2-\frac{1}{n}$$
but whats really confusing me is the $a_{n}$ term how do i manipulate that first equation to get that any help is much appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$ Then, sum up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Use that

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

and think about a Telescoping Sum on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Let $(b_n)$ the second sequence. Show $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ satisfy the same recurrence relation and the same initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We can also proceed by induction

- base case: $n=1 \implies a_1=1$
- induction step:

$$a_n=2-\frac{1}{n}\implies a_{n+1}=2-\frac{1}{n+1}$$